# UILabel text not shown as expected

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am experiencing a very curious issue in a viewController.

I am defining a UILabel to show a NSDictionary object key value, in this case @"nombreEmpresa".

The same value is used as viewController title and as label text value.

When the app is launched, the viewController sets its title with the key value, but the label doesn't show the text.

I think everything is ok, I have referenced the UILabel in the connections director:

[image]

I have implemented  the property in the header file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nombreLabel;
```

I have synthesise the property in the implementation file:

```
@synthesize detalleDescription,nombreLabel;
```

And that is the way I have implemented the key value to set the viewController title and the label text:

```
NSString *category = [detalleDescription objectForKey:@"nombreEmpresa"];

self.title = category;

nombreLabel.text = category;
```

Now, in the screenshot you may see that the title (MAREA BAJA is the value for the object key) is well shown, but the label is empty.

[image]

ANy help is welcome.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're synthesizing on your own? Assuming you're using Xcode 5, properties are auto-synthesized. You're synthesizing could be messing with the property reference. Just a guess.

Comment: Thank you @hw731, I have tried out with and without synthesizing.

Comment: Where is the line `nombreLabel.text = category` ? Is it in `-viewDidLoad` ?

Comment: Yes, it is in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I bet `detalleDescription` and `category` are `nil`. It doesn't look like you're showing the title either. Are you positive that `detalleDescription` is the value that you think that it is?

Comment: @Aaron I am logging the viewDidLoad method and I have detected that it is called two times, the first time the log values are correct, and the second time, they are nil. ANy idea why it is called twice?

Comment: It is solved, I was opening the viewController twice, one from the previous viewController didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, and the second from a storyBoard segue. After removing the segue, the label is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should connect your IBOutlet label to File's Owner.

[image]

Comment: I think it is already done, please check if what you mean is done in my first picture.

Comment: I am looking at the pic but the 'nombreLabel' is not tied to File's Owner.

Comment: I think it is done, the IBOutlet is tied from storyBoard to the header file.

Comment: Done as in you re-did the connection? If so then it should say File's Owner (like in the pic).

Comment: The label is ok, if I put a nombreLabel.text = @"Test text"; the label is shown. That means that there is something weard with viewDidLoad method. It is called twice, the first time the key values are oK, the second time, the key values are nil.

Comment: It is solved, I was opening the viewController twice, one from the previous viewController didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, and the second from a storyBoard segue. After removing the segue, the label is shown.